# My keras neural network model is giving me accuracy 0.0000e+00

Tags: python-3.x, keras, neural-network

I am trying to code a simple neural network to predict total number of corona cases given a multiple of factors related to each country.
However when using the dataset I created, the accuracy in 0.0000e+00. Although I tried this code on a different dataset I downloaded online concerning house pricing and the accuracy went up to 60%. 
Both datasets are around 200 rows.

Here is my code below.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel (r'Dataset2.xlsx', sheet_name='class 2')
df.head()

dataset = df.values
X = dataset[:,1:7]
Y = dataset[:,7]
from sklearn import preprocessing

min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
X_scale = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(X)
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split( X, Y, test_size=0.1, random_state=4)

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
model = Sequential([    Dense(32, activation='relu', input_shape=(6,)),    Dense(32, activation='relu'),    Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'),])

model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mse',metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=25, batch_size=32,  verbose=1, validation_data=(X_test,y_test))
```

Also here is a [screenshot of my dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjygW.png).

Comment: Hi, it seems to me that you are trying to do a regression problem here. Try changing your output activation from `sigmoid` to `linear` and try it. There is not enough detail on what you are trying to do with your network. Can you elaborate more on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accuracy is a metric for classification, while from your description your task is regression. Use different metrics suitable for regression task, such as MAE or MSE.

Comment: Thank you so much. I used mse and i got a val_mse = 6.4e-04. Is that too low or is this acceptable?

Comment: MSE (unlike accuracy) should be as low as possible, ideally zero. Your value seems good, but in general it depends on task.